# Do I have to cancel an answer that has been accepted that has arrived simultaneously with another one?

Tags: discussion

I have written an answer in contemporaneity with another posted e few seconds before. Answers are approximately the same. Both have up-vote and mine was accepted by the questioner.

Have I to delete the accepted answer because mine is arrived later?

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508929/what-is-the-maximum-value-with-set-seed/49509097#comment86023433_49509097) in question.

Comment: No, you don't. And you can't, since you can't delete accepted answers.

Comment: Hi @Cath, there is a difference related to the acceptance of the answer in my question

Comment: In my opinion, people should not be giving you grief over a time difference of less than *90 seconds*. They definitely shouldn't have been asking you to delete *after* your answer was accepted.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror, I agree with Karel that I think your answer is more qualitative. I appreciate your help and apologize for what has happened to you. I did not mean to arouse conflict...... Please do let me know if you have any further decision on this issue and I'll follow up.

Comment: Thank you @HW-Scientist for your kindly attention. I'm not upset about what happened, I'm just curious to know what's the right way to proceed in this kind of situations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can happen with everyone. It is kind of you that you want to delete your answer because of posting it 2 minutes "late". I do it myself too if there is another answer but only if it is better detailed than mine. Since your answer got marked as accepted answer, you cannot delete it. Just leave it there. Or ask the OP to mark the other's answer as accepted so that you can delete yours.

From my personal view, I find your answer more qualitative than Roland's answer.

Comment: Another alternative is to review your answer and further improve/refine it if possible.

Comment: I would add, more *quantity* is not necessarily "better". There have been instances when a competing responder has provided 6 potential solutions with no explanation, and I've provided 1 of those + explanation. Both posted at the same time (within minutes). And I have intentionally kept my answer + explanation because I believe the other 5 from the other post are not appropriate.

Comment: @jpp that is true; but that all falls at the responsibility of the posters. I do delete mine as said. But there are ofc that does not. It is their choice.